# Configuring Python root logging only

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python package `foobar` with `__main__.py` inside it. In the `__main__.py` I configure logging with:

```
from logging import config

config.dictConfig(
    {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': True,
        'formatters': {
            'simple': {
                'format': '%(message)s',
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'simple',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            # No idea why is this necessary.
            'foobar': {
                'propagate': True,
            },
        },
        'root': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': [
                'console',
            ],
        },
    },
)
```

I simply want all messages from all loggers from all packages to be logged to the console, DEBUG level and above. I thought that configuring the root logger will be enough, but it is not. I had to add `foobar` entry in `loggers` and explicitly mark it for propagation. Why? Without that, nothing is logged out to the console from my module when I run it with `python3 -m foobar`.

I tried this on Python 3.8.5.

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like but if the foobar module logger exists before you call basicConfig the disable_existing_loggers option will disable it.

Comment: I described it above, `basicConfig` is called inside `__main__.py` inside `foobar` module. Does this mean it exists before?

Comment: It seems so. Setting `disable_existing_loggers` to `False` works.